# How do you bench on a Friday rosh chodesh if you eat after kabbolas shabbos before nightfall

Tags: halacha, shabbat, bentching, rosh-chodesh-new-month, leil-shabbat

Do we say yaaleh v'yovo or r'tsai or both if one eats today which is Friday rosh chodesh after being mekabel shabbos but before nightfall. Does it make a difference if you finish before or after nightfall.

Comment: If you Daven early are you saying Yaale V'Yovo by Maariv?, No! Then why would you say it by bentching?

Comment: @Gershon Gold I can think of a difference. The maariv t'filla is not part of rosh chodesh. The day is still rosh chodesh and one cant change it by being mekabel shabbos.

Answer (score 2):

If you davened Ma'ariv (early, BeTzibur), then Rosh Chodesh has effectively ended and Kedushas Shabbos has taken over, even if it still daylight outside.  Therefore, you bench Retseh (for Shabbos) and not Ya'aleh V'Yavo (for R.H.).  See [Mishna Berura, 424:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40448&st=&pgnum=181), (on the right hand side), also referencing Magen Avraham, there.  Saying both might be considered a stira (contradiction).

If all you did was MeKabel Shabbos (by saying Mizmor Shir...) and you right away made Kiddush, with the intention of davening Ma'ariv later (Bizmana), then consult your L.O.R.

Comment: Please provide some proof otherwise this answer is unacceptable.

Comment: See Mishna Berura, 424:2, http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40448&st=&pgnum=181 (on the right hand side), also referencing Magen Avraham, there.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your source into your answer, as it's integral to it.

Comment: What if you don't plan on davening maariv?

Comment: Thusly rules Yalqut Yosef